# Synchronized method does not work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a variable which is shared by two threads. The two threads will do some operations on it. I don't know why the result of sharedVar is different every time I execute the program.

```
public class Main
{
    public static int sharedVar = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread();
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread();
        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();

        try
        {
            // wait for the threads
            mt1.join();
            mt2.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(sharedInt); // I expect this value to be 20000, but it's not
    }
}
```

The following is the class "MyThread"

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private int times = 10000;
    private synchronized void addOne()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
        {
            Main.sharedVar ++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        addOne();
    }
}
```

The final result of sharedVar sometimes are 13735, 12508, or 18793; but never 20000, which is the result I expect. Another interesting thing about the program is when times=1000. I always get 2000 as the final result.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Try making sharedVar volatile.

Comment: After adding volatile to sharedVar, the result gets closer to 20000, but still below 20000.

Comment: The reason that volatile alone doesn't work, is because `Main.sharedVar++` is a compound operation (read-increment-write). Volatile offers no protection for that.

Comment: I see, so AtomicLong will work.

Comment: If your code would work like this, I'd like to note that it's probably still not what you want. Your code would then ensure that first, one thread does 10000 increments, then the other thread does 10000 increments. What it would not do is let both threads increment (at the scheduler's discretion, more or less) alternately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A synchronized method protects the resource `this` that means that your code is equivalent to:

```
private void addOne()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
        {
            Main.sharedVar ++;
        }
    }
}
```

But you have 2 objects for which `addOne` method is called. That means `this` for `mt1.addOne` is not the same than `this` for `mt2.addOne` and therefore you don't have a common resource of synchronization.

Try changing yout `addOne` code to:

```
private void addOne()
{
    synchronized(MyThread.class)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
        {
            Main.sharedVar ++;
        }
    }
}
```

And you will observe the expected behaviour. As the comments below suggest, it is better to use a different object than `MyThread.class` for synchronization since class objects are accesible from many points and it is easy that other code may try to synchronize using the same object.

Comment: Don't lock on the class.. Use some other object as lock. +1 anyways :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah you are right, it is better to lock other object but I wanted to write some draft code where a common object is used as synchronization resource.

Comment: I don't know why both "synchronized(MyThread.class)" and "synchronized(Main.class)" work.

Comment: @lyen - They work because there is only *one class object* for both classes.

Comment: Change "int sharedVar = 0;" to "Integer sharedVar = new Integer(0);", then you can lock sharedVar by typing "synchronized(Main.sharedVar)".

Comment: @lyen no, because Integer is immutable. each increment sets the variable to a new object

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo - You are not wrong.. It is just that it is a *bad practice* to lock on *class Objects*. :)

Comment: @SillyFreak - You are right.. But *why* increment it? :P

Comment: @TheLostMind, what do you mean, incrementing sharedVar is what this is all about?

Comment: @SillyFreak - I meant we should use `AtomicInteger` instead of `Integer` in multi-threaded environment. Next, if you use `Integer` as a lock, then don't increment it. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `synchronized` on non-static method, you use current object as monitor.

When you use `synchronized` on static method, you use current object of class (`ClassName.class` static field) as monitor.

In your case, you use `synchronized` on Thread's object (2 different instances), so two different threads will modify your `sharedVar` static field at same time.

You can fix it in different ways.

Move `addOne` method to `Main` and make it `static`.

```
private static synchronized void addOne(int times)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    {
        sharedVar++;
    }
}
```

Or you can create class called `SharedVar` with field `private int var;` and method `synchronized void addOne(int times)` and pass single instance of `SharedVar` to your treads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SharedVar var = new SharedVar();
    MyThread mt1 = new MyThread(var);
    MyThread mt2 = new MyThread(var);
    mt1.start();
    mt2.start();

    try
    {
        // wait for the threads
        mt1.join();
        mt2.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(var.getVar()); // I expect this value to be 20000, but it's not
}
```

But if you need only one integer to be changed in multiple threads, you can use classes from `java.til.concurrent.*`, like `AtomicLong` or `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Define `sharedVar` as an `AtomicLong` instead of `int`. Making the function `synchronized` works as well but it is less efficient because you only need the increment to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread is about to execute a '**synchronized**' **instance method**, it aqcuires the lock on the Object(to be precise, lock on that object monitor).

So in your case, Thread mt1 acquires lock on Object mt1 and Thread mt2 acquires lock on Object mt2 and they do not block each Other as the two threads are working on two different locks.

And when two threads modify a shared variable concurrently(not synchronized way), the result is unpredictable.

Well about the case of value 1000, for smaller inputs the interleaved execution might have resulted in correct result(luckily).

Sol : remove the synchronized keyword from addOne method and make sharedVal as type of '**AtomicInteger**'

Answer (score 0):

Join the thread immediately after start method. From this thread-1 will start and go to dead state after that thread-2 will start and go to dead state. So it will print your expected output always.

Change the code as shown below:-

```
public class Main{

    public static int sharedVar = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)

        {
            MyThread mt1 = new MyThread();
            MyThread mt2 = new MyThread();

            try

                {
                    mt1.start();
                    mt1.join();
                    mt2.start();
                    mt2.join();
                }

            catch (InterruptedException e1)

                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            System.out.println(sharedVar);

        }
}

class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private int times = 1000000;

    private synchronized void addOne()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
                {
                    Main.sharedVar++;
                }
        }

    @Override
    public void run()
        {
            addOne();
        }
}
```